# Gradle - Add conditional classpath in buildscript dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have updated to Android Studio 2.2, which uses by default the Gradle Plugin v2.2.0, and is much better for debugging purposes. For disribution purposes, I must still use v2.1.3. I was thinking of adding a conditional command in the project gradle script, but I am not sure how to do it.
The following test works

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        if (project.name.startsWith("X"))
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
        else
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        }
    }
}
```

But I need it to be something like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        if (IS_RELEASE_VERSION)
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
        else
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        }
    }
}
```

and I cannot figure out how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing comes to mind that would make this possible. The real problem here is: why do you have to use an older version for releases?

Comment: We use am additional plugin for our releases, and it only is compatible with 2.1.3

Comment: Then you are probably going to have to stick with the old version. You cannot use a different version for debug and release builds. If it was about something else in your build.gradle - like a library version or some setting - then it wouldn't be a problem. But buildscript dependencies are literally dependencies for the build script itself. The concept of debug and release builds is something that is defined by the build script and it can't be evaluated until the buildscript dependencies are loaded.

Comment: However I can think of a workaround: You can inject a parameter on your build server and use that in your if. On your development machines you can set the parameter to the develop version in the .gradle.properties file in your home folder. However that isn't really a great solution... but it would work.

Comment: That won't work for me, as I use same machine. Is there a way, to set a flag (even if I have to edit gradle file). I tried using `def buildingDistributionVesrion = true;` but it didn't work in the `buildscripts`, as I believe the `buildscripts` are handled before the defines.

Comment: I suggest you set a parameter in the global gradle.properties (located in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties, if it doesn't exist just create it), maybe somethin like like `build_type=debug`. Then when you make a release build append this in your terminal `-Pbuild_type=release`. This will change the value of the `build_type` parameter just for that one build, in all other cases the value will fall back on the one defined in your global `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks, I actually added it to the build.gradle of the project directory. I would love to know if there is a way to pass the -P paramater using AndroidStudio, only in the "Generate Signed APK".

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You should really get a build server.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thanks for your help. It got me thinking. I just posted a simple working answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I believe I solved it, and it is very simple. You need to check the `gradle.startParameter.taskNames` property. Here is how I coded it:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.size() > 0 && gradle.startParameter.taskNames.get(0).contains("Release"))
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
        else
        {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        }
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

So far it is working fine. If you prefer, you can change the "Release" value, to a flavor variant (if you are using flavors).