# What's the appropriate way to make some lib only contained in the debug version of Android app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For some reason I have to add some tool in the debug version of my Android app, and make the Application like:

```java
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HelperTool.init(context);
            HelperTool.setUserId(accountId);
            HelperTool.getService(IBackService.class).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And in order to import the `HelperTool` in the Java code base, I add some dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "http://mirrors.internalsite.com/repository/maven/helpertool" }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("com.internalsite.hlper.gradle:hlper-app-plugin:1.0.0")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.internalsite.hlper'
```

The helpertool is kind of large for its size, it contains some 3rd SO libs to help debug, I'd tried the [Gradle - Add conditional classpath in buildscript dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602978/gradle-add-conditional-classpath-in-buildscript-dependencies) as:

```
dependencies {
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.size() > 0 && gradle.startParameter.taskNames.get(0).contains("Debug"))
    {
        classpath("com.internalsite.hlper.gradle:hlper-app-plugin:1.0.0")
    }

if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().toLowerCase().contains("debug")) {
```

But the Application java file couldn't import the helper lib in this case.

I was wondering what's the appropriate way to make some lib only contained in the debug version of Android app?

Answer (score 3):

One pattern to do it:

1. Include the library in debug builds only with gradle dependency `debugImplementation` instead of `implementation`.
2. Call the library only in debug build wrapping the calls in code under `debug` source set rather than the default `main`. To make the `release` build compile too, have an empty stub implementation of the wrapping code under the `release` sourceset. `BuildConfig.DEBUG` conditional does not work since the imported symbols need to be in place for the code to compile.

Comment: I just went through it, and tried to use the `debugImplementation`, but I realized that's a gradle plugin, not a lib, we could only enable it by `if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().toLowerCase().contains("debug")) {apply plugin: 'com.internalsite.hlper'}`. But once again, I couldn't import the dependencies in the `debug` source set as in `class DebugApplication : Application()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `implementation` you can use `debugImplementation` so your library will only compile on debug builds
for more information
https://www.programmersought.com/article/4521840415/

Answer (score 0):

After some Google search, I got the solution from [Adding and using debug build specific dependencies in Android](https://ashishkumar468.medium.com/adding-and-using-debug-build-specific-dependencies-in-android-d4c82dda0908)

I just created a new module, and modified the `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "http://mirrors.internalsite.com/repository/maven/helpertool" }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("com.internalsite.hlper.gradle:hlper-app-plugin:1.0.0")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.internalsite.hlper'
```

Then add the new module in the main `build.gradle`:

```
debugImplementation project(':helpertool')
```

Finally, in the debug root source:

```kotlin
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...

        HelperTool.init(context);
        HelperTool.setUserId(accountId);
        HelperTool.getService(IBackService.class).show();
    }
}
```

No need for the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` :p